Spring Security - No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context but already set http use-expression=true
My web.xml is
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value> 
 </context-param>

and inside /WEB-INF/spring/ folder has my applicationContext-slis-security.xml, with http tag as follow:
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/adminSysParm/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_001','ROLE_002')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_001')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/downloadRestrictedSection/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_001')" />
        <!--  <intercept-url pattern="/**/downloadRestrictedSection/**" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_001')" />-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_001','ROLE_002')" />
        <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="webSEALFilter" />
        <custom-filter after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myFilter"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/accessDenied"/>
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout"/>  
        <session-management invalid-session-url="${${ENV}.login.url}">
            <concurrency-control expired-url="${${ENV}.login.url}" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

and my index.jsp has use authorize tag as follow:
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_001')">
        <li><a ng-click="reload()" href="./#/adminAnnouncement">Administration</a></li>
</security:authorize>

but the following error is thrown:

ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception
handling request to /SLIS/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp:
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: jakarta.servlet.jsp.JspException:
java.io.IOException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance
could be found in the application context. There must be at least one
in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.  at
io.undertow.jsp@2.2.6.Final//org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:888)
at
io.undertow.jsp@2.2.6.Final//org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:820)
at
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:482)
.......

I see many website mentioned need to add
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" />

in Spring Security configuration file http tag, but although I already added in, why still have this error?
____________ Edit _______________
Don't know the reason, but if I add the following in my applicationContext-slis-security.xml, the problem is disappeared.
<beans:bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

Although I see many site mentioned set http tag use-expressions="true" already enough, like in the following link
https://www.waitingforcode.com/tips/spring/an-error-occured-using-authorize-tag-in-jsp

Another way to activate it, is the use of use-expressions attribute in
 tags in Spring Security configuration file, as below:

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" />

